# Compatibility level for SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, compatibility

My database hoster allows to restore SQL Server databases with a compatibility level of 90 (SQL Server 2005). My database is created locally with a compatibility level of 100 (SQL Server 2008).

So, I generated script of my database (version 2008) and run in SQL Server 2005, backup and restore to my database hoster, it works. Currently I do likes it.

And then I found [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) that can change compatibility level of database likes

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = { 90 | 100 | 110 }

 90 = SQL Server 2005
 100 = SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2
 110 = SQL Server 2012
```

I turn my database compatibility level using this script in SQL Server 2008, backup my database and restore to my database hoster. But it doesn't work. I want to know why? Is there a better way to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't go back to version compatibility of sql server better to go through scripts.

Answer (score 10):

You can **NEVER** restore a database from a newer version of SQL Server (like your **2008** version) onto an older SQL Server (2005) instance.

No matter what you try, no trick, no hack, no workaround - it just **cannot be done**.

The compatibility level doesn't make any difference either. It just makes your newer database (like on 2008) behave as if it were an older one (like 2005) - so the features you can use are limited to what the older database supported.

But internally - it's still a **2008 database** and it **cannot** be restored to a 2005 instance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a new database
2. Import the tables in the new database
3. Then generate the script of procedures and functions and run this script on the new database